# Is there an inequality between integral of product and sum of integral of function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Given a $L^2(D)$ space and two real-valued time dependent functions $f(x,t) $ and $g(x,t)$ defined on $D$.
I was wondering if there is an inequality like
$$
\int_D |f.g| dxdt \leq \int_D |f| dxdt + \int_D |g| dxdt
$$

Thank you!

Comment: Not the inequality you have. A correct one would be for example Young’s inequality $ab\leq \frac{a^p}{p}+\frac{b^q}{q}$. Or in the case $p=q=2$, just $ab\leq (a^2+b^2)/2$; this is the one you wanna use in your case.

Comment: It's basically what @peek-a-boo said, but maybe you are searching for Hölder's Inequality  applied on 2-dimensional Lebesgue Measure (or a restriction of it). See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality